# Hiding multi selected options - react-select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

Using react-select to have a select dropdown which allows async options loading and multi select. The default behavior of the library renders the selected options next to the input itself:
[image]

But I want to show the selected options in the options list rather than in the select header. I have achieved that by passing the Custom Option component. Here is the working example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-hellman-yidqn

And now I want to remove/hide the selected options from the header.
Also I want to show the placeholder back when focus is out of the input.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want the tags to show up in the input field, you can disable that by adding the attribute `controlShouldRenderValue={false}` to the item.

Comment: Awesome, `controlShouldRenderValue={false}` worked like charm, you saved a lot of time and code for me +1 for this !!!